Sharepoint API - OData Query negative substringof not working
I'm starting to get acquainted to the Sharepoint API and wanted to fetch all of the file names that do not contain the substring "done". Until now I was not able to achieve it using a couple of combinations, such as:
f"{API_BASE}/files?$filter= substringof('done',Url) eq false"

which outputs an error:

{'request_error_message': '{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}}'}

Am I doing something wrong?

what about the filter query not(contains(Url,'done'))

contains is not supported by the SP API.

To fetch all file names in SharePoint API OData Query that do not contain the substring "done", you can use the substringof function in the $filter parameter of the query. Here is an example query:
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef&$filter=not substringof('done',FileLeafRef)

This query selects the FileLeafRef property (which contains the file name) of all items in the specified list where the file name does not contain the substring "done".
